# Where does Desktop Telegram save sent pictures?

Tags: telegram

I use telegram with my PC. I know that telegram saves all pictures in a folder on android, is it also saving them on the PC? If so, where?

Answer (score 6):

It usually saves pictures here: `~/Downloads/Telegram Desktop/Pictures`

Comment: Temp path for photo files is `/<HOME_USERS>/<USERNAME>/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/tdata/tdld`

Answer (score 1):

if you send a picture as a file, telegram doesn't save the sent picture in a separate location. It just holds the address of picture which now are located. So if you change location of that picture or rename it, you see that telegram needs to download your sent picture.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sent images, but received ones are in the folder you can configure in Settings > Download Path (default is a subfolder of your system's Download folder).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the folder is:

1. Open a conversation in wich you have sent a file on Windows OS version of Telegram.
2. Right click on “OPEN WITH” link which is located just under of file.
3. Click on “Show in Folder”.
4. Now you are in the saving folder of Telegram.

If for whatever reason the above method doesn't work, try using your PC's browser and search for "Telegram Desktop"

Credits to [Filelocations](https://www.filelocations.com/where-does-telegram-save-files-android-ios-pc/)